# <p> tag keeps wrapping on image

Tags: html, css

```
<div class=menu-icon><img src="img"></div>
 <div class="menu-info">
   <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
```

The icon is 85px wide, but once I add 3+ `<p>` tags it starts wrapping and it won't center.

```css
.menu-info{text-align:center;}
.menu-icon{margin-right: 10px;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapping"? Are any elements floated? You haven't provided sufficient code to recreate the problem - please ensure you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or we'll only be able to make guesses as to what the problem is.

Comment: It would also help to get a screenshot or a link to the actual problem so we can see what went wrong. A jsfiddle would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<img />` tag is self closing, you have to close the `<img />` tag, like this : `<img src='img' />`, that is proper html. If you want the text on top of the image, use `z-index` and `position: absolute`